# Vector layer does not export properly to PDF when "Inverted Polygons" option is selected

Tags: qgis, export, pdf, qgis-export

I have a vector layer of country borders:

[image]

I can export it to PDF correctly (Project → Import/Export → Export Map to PDF).

If I then select the "Inverted Polygons" option...

[image]

..I get this, which is what I want:

[image]

But then if I try to export this to PDF again, I get something messed up:

[image]

What's happening? How can I export to PDF correctly with the Inverted Polygons option?

EDIT to answer comments:

(1) QGIS-LTR version when the question was originally posted: 3.22.7 (Białowieża). I then updated my QGIS-LTR version to 3.28.10 (Firenze), but I still get the error.
(2) If I export as a raster, I do get the correct result. I would like to export in a non-raster format.

EDIT 2: If I use GforGIS's method, I still get the problem:

EDIT 3: Here is the offending file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yvEcOKE1r6nBWCxHn9C4yDJXKsJ4UOeU/view?usp=sharing

[image]

Edit 4: I figured it out with the help of GforGIS. The solution is to uncheck a box called "simplify geometries to reduce output file size" in the Advanced section of the "Export to PDF settings":

[image]

Comment: I 'm not able to reproduce your problem using latest QGIS version (3.32.2) and default setting for PDF export. Looking at your result it look like you get oversimplified polygon. Could you update your question with your exact QGIS version and PDF export setting ? (you could also check your layer for geometry error as these tend to manifest in unexpected way)

Comment: Also did you try to export as image rather than PDF ? If yes did you get the same result ?

Comment: Try to export it from a print layout instead. It should work.

Comment: @J.R I get the problem in QGIS-LTR 3.22.7 (Białowieża), QGIS-LTR 3.28.10 (Firenze), and QGIS 3.32.2 (Lima). If I export to raster, I get the correct result (but I would still like a non-raster export).

Comment: Can you share the data?

Comment: @GforGIS Sure here it is: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yvEcOKE1r6nBWCxHn9C4yDJXKsJ4UOeU/view?usp=drive_link

Comment: @Pertinax I need you to grant me access for downloading the files.

Comment: @GforGIS Right, I believe you should have access now: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yvEcOKE1r6nBWCxHn9C4yDJXKsJ4UOeU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Pertinax it works fine for me, no issues. Could you update your question and post the screenshot of the settings before exporting to pdf? Also could you please share your pdf as well?

Comment: @GforGIS I figured it out when you asked me to screenshot the settings. There is a box called "Simplify geometries to reduce output file size" in these settings that needs to be unchecked (see image added to main post). If you would like to modify your answer to use this solution, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a print layout then export it to PDF, it supports Geospatial PDF as well.That's the method I always use.

[image]

[image]

**Note:**
When exporting to SVG, make sure you do not select on "Simplfy geometries ..." from the *"layout menu"*, see screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for trying, but I still get the same problem with your method (see edit to main post).